# Pagination Not Showing on Category Pages - Magento 1

Tags: magento-1.9, catalog, pagination

For some reason, Pagination is not showing on all of our category pages.

I've looked at other question on here and from what I've learned you need the **page/html_pager** block within catalog.xml for the category.

In this file we have a few instances of  and they all have this **page/html_pager** block.

Any ideas why the pagination is not showing?

Comment: Have you checked your pagination is set to display none or not. May be you have set it to none.

Comment: Yes. The area where this is meant to be output is an empty div tag. There is not a `display: none;` on this area.

Comment: disable all third party extension than after clear cache session. and than check